# How important is file path length?

Tags: c, unicode, path

I'm working on crossplatform library which will be used to file manipulations (create, rename, delete, ...) on optical media. So I have questions related to path handling.

1. Currently I have no restriction on path length in my library, so user can create folder with very long path which is not supported by OS. For example in windows user can create folder with pathlen bigger that `MAX_PATH` characters. So what I must do in this situation?
2. Solution for first question, maybe checking new path len which will created after file/folder copying. But there is another problem, caused by different values of MAX_PATH and PATH_MAX in windows and linux.

Comment: I think you might have to consider the optical media as well. Seem to remember that CD standard has shorter path length than Windows.

Comment: Exactly I'm working with Bluray and DVD media and I'm creating UDF 2.50 file system, so there is no restrictions, which were in CD's ISO file system.

Comment: Windows actually allows around 32k 16-bit code units per path.

Answer (score 0):

`C` defines a standard macro `FILENAME_MAX`.

*"This macro constant expands to an integral expression corresponding to the size needed
for an array of char elements to hold the longest file name string allowed by the
system. Or, if the system imposes no such restriction, it is set to the recommended
size for character arrays intended to hold any file name."*

This should be large enough to specify a string which holds the longest name which can be used for a file name. It's a macro so that its value is platform-dependent.

Most OS APIS should return a speicific error indicating that the name is too handle, you can properly handle it and report back to user.

Comment: In the case when user copies file to some destination folder, there is no problem for detecting is path length is ok or not. But what in the case of folder? Because folder's path itself can fit the length limitations, but what about this folder's children? What I must do in this situation. Before starting copying I must check all children of folder to correctness of their path length?

Comment: I think that depends on your needs. If you want ensure an atomic copying, i.e., no single file will be copied to the destination folder if any of the file name is too long, then you'll need pre-scan the files-to-copy recursively, and copy them if none exceeds the maximum name length. Otherwise, you can just check and copy them one by one ;)

Comment: Thank for your answer, I must think about it)

Comment: The wording in the [current draft](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) is a bit clearer: “[…] size needed for an array of char large enough to hold the longest file name string that the implementation guarantees can be opened”—so there may be file names supported by the operating system that the implementation (i.e., the C library) doesn’t support. In fact, this has always been the case with MSVC where the standard C functions don’t support Unicode filenames.